# File download with php

Tags: php, download

I have a php script to be downloading a file from a remote server (the website is hosted on bluehost), but when I click on the download link (button), the following stuff which I don't really get opens in my browser:

> ����ELRY`gnu|����������������&/8AKT]gqz������������!-8COZfr~���������� -;HUcq~��������� +:IXgw��������'7HYj{�������+=Oat�������2FZn�������        %   :   O   d   y   �   �   �   �   �   �  ' = T j � � � � � �"9Qi������*C\u����� & @ Z t � � � � �.Id����  %A^z���� &Ca~����1Om����&Ed����#Cc����'Ij����4Vx���&Il����Ae����@e���� Ek���*Qw���;c���*R{���Gp���@j���>i���  A l � � �!!H!u!�!�!�"'"U"�"�"�# #8#f#�#�#�$$M$|$�$�% %8%h%�%�%�&'&W&�&�&�''I'z'�'�( (?(q(�(�))8)k)�)�**5*h*�*�++6+i+�+�,,9,n,�,�--A-v-�-�..L.�.�.�/$/Z/�/�/�050l0�0�11J1�1�1�2*2c2�2�3 3F33�3�4+4e4�4�55M5�5�5�676r6�6�7$7`7�7�88P8�8�99B99�9�:6:t:�:�;-;k;�;�<' >`>�>�?!?a?�?

Below is the code I'm using

```
function output_file($file_id=0)
{
 /*
 This function takes a path to a file to output ($file),  the filename that the browser will see ($name) and  the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).
 */
 //get filepath, filename and mime type from db
 $mysql_file = "SELECT filename, file_format
    FROM order_files
    WHERE order_files.fileID ={$file_id}";

    $myresult_file = mysql_query($mysql_file);
    if($myresult_file){
        while($myrow_file = mysql_fetch_array($myresult_file)){
            $filename = $myrow_file['filename'];
            $mimeType =$myrow_file['file_format'] ;
        }


    }

$file = '/home6/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/inc/orderfiles/'.$filename;
$name = $filename;
$mime_type=$mimeType;   

 //Check the file premission
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 /* Figure out the MIME type | Check in array */
 $known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
    "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
     $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
     if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
     } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
     };
 };

 //turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
 @ob_end_clean(); 

 // required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
  ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

 /* The three lines below basically make the 
    download non-cacheable */
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

 // multipart-download and download resuming support
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
 {
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
    }
    /*
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This application is developed by www.webinfopedia.com
    //visit www.webinfopedia.com for PHP,Mysql,html5 and Designing tutorials for FREE!!!
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    $new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
    header("Content-Length: $new_length");
    header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
 } else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
 }

 /* Will output the file itself */
 $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
 $bytes_send = 0;
 if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
 {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

    while(!feof($file) && 
        (!connection_aborted()) && 
        ($bytes_send<$new_length)
          )
    {
        $buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
        print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // can also possible
        flush();
        $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
    }
 fclose($file);
 } else
 //If no permissiion
 die('Error - can not open file.');
 //die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);
```

What does this mean and how do I debug it?
I'm new to php, your assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: I guess the issue is $mime_type="application/force-download"; change it to 'application/octet-stream';

Comment: you're reading the file and printing the contents when you do this `$buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);print($buffer);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you force file to download instead of display in browser

http://hiryu.byethost7.com/2013/06/force-file-download-in-php/

try this
add these headers

```
 header("Content-Type: " . $file_head['Content-Type']);
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
  header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($url) . ";");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Content-Length: " . $file_head['Content-Length']);
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Connection: close");
```

Comment: While external links here are not discouraged, if the link you have provided becomes invalid so will this answer. You should instead paste some of the code from the link which you think are needed and quote the link as reference.